# Windows does not recognize the `bin` of NPM package

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I created a simple NPM package. On my Linux machine I run it as:

```
npx mypkg

//or
npm i mypgk -g && mypkg

//or
npm i mypkg && npx mypkg
```

And it runs.

I have done it on Windows but in any case I get:

> the system can not find the path specified

The **node_modules** folder is there though, and if I run:

```
node ./node_modules/mypkg/src/index.js
```

It runs.

My **package.json** is like this:

```
{ bin: { "mpkg": "../src/index.js" } }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The name in the **bin** has to be the package name. [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin):

> If you have a single executable, and its name should be the name of the package, then you can just supply it as a string. For example:
>
> ```
> { "name": "my-program"
> , "version": "1.2.5"
> , "bin": "./path/to/program" }
> ```

---

So for example, my program was called "hello-world" in npm, then in the **package.json** I wrote:

```
bin : {"hw":"./src/index.js"}
```

I did it in purpose as **typescript** does with **tsc**, but I noticed most software uses *the same name* in the bin to the npm package. And so I did:

```
bin : {"hello-world":"./src/index.js"}
```

And now, at least, windows is able to run `npx hello-world`.